# WinError 10061 Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: python, django, email

При отправке письма для изменения пароля или подтверждений регистрации выдаёт эту ошибку.

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = ''

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'projectm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'projectm.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = '/static/'


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.AdvUser'

# Рассылка сообщений
EMIAL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMIAL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index, BBLoginView, profile
from .views import BBLogoutView, ChangePasswordView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetDoneView
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetCompleteView

app_name='main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/reset/done/', 
        PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
        template_name = 'registration/password_confirmed.html'),
        name = 'password_reset_complete'),

    path('accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name = 'registration/confirm_password.html'),
        name = 'password_reset_confirm'),

    path('accounts/password_reset/done/',
        PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name = 'registration/password_reset_done.html'),
        name = 'password_reset_done' ),

    path('accounts/password_reset/', 
        PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name = 'registration/reset_password.html',
        subject_template_name = 'registration/reset_subject.txt',
        email_template_name = 'registration/reset_email.html',
        success_url = reverse_lazy('main:password_reset_done')),
        name = 'password_reset'),


    path('accounts/password/change/', ChangePasswordView.as_view(),
        name = 'password_change'),

    path('accounts/login/', BBLoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', BBLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name = 'profile' ),
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Поискав в интернете я понял, что у меня в settings.py не хватало нескольких настроек

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'admin@mail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'admin@mail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Но появилась другая проблема [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed